# Addition Amplifier equation doesn't seem to work

Tags: amplifier

[image: image of the addition amplifier]

In this addition amplifier, when I set V1=5V, V2=5V, R1=3.3kOhm R2=10kOhm, the answer (theoretically) should be -20.15V, but the actual result is -13.04V. Why is this happening? Is the equation for the addition amplifier wrong? Or is something wrong with the amplifier?

The supply voltage was +/-15V, and the equation that I am referring to is

V_0=-(R_2/R_11 v1 + R_2/R_12 v2), where R_2 =10kOhm in this case

Thank you!

Comment: What is the power supply for the circuit?

Comment: You asked if your equation is wrong but you haven't provided an equation. As W5VO points out, you also haven't mentioned your supply rails. If you have a +/- 15V supply, then your measured results make sense as the 741 does not go rail-to-rail. Can you please provide information of your supply voltage, and go through your math for your output voltage? Just so we have all the information

Comment: I have edited my question and answered your questions!

Comment: *but the actual result is -13.04V* How did you get this result? Is it measured, simulated? A 741 opamp is **not ideal** when its supply rails are +15 V and - 15 V it can only output voltages reliably between around +13 V to -13 V.

Comment: So your supply is +/- 15 V. Why do you expect the opamp to be able to output -20.15 V???

Comment: Ohhh so there's a limit... I didn't know! Thank you!

Comment: But then I have another question... why does it cap at 13V? Is there like a component level explanation for that?

Comment: by the way, -13.04 was measured

Comment: In the datasheet (http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm741.pdf) on page 5 the output voltage swing is only guaranteed to go to +/-12V.

Comment: Thank you!! but i wonder, why does there exist a output range in the first place?

Comment: That output range is a consequence of the design of the opamp. Some opamps have a wider output voltage range than the 741, some don't. No opamps exist which can output a voltage beyond their supply voltage. Why would you expect an opamp **not** to have a limited output voltage range?

Comment: Well, I guess if you say like that that makes sense, but  I'm just curious as to how exactly the value '13V' was set as the limit. Sure, it could be measured through experiments, but is there a theoretical way to derive this?

Comment: The "13 V" isn't set as a limit, the limit is around 2 V **less** than the supply voltage. To understand where the "around 2 V" comes from you would need to study analog circuit analysis. This isn't something that can be explained in a few sentences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now you have provided the supply voltages, it seems I was correct in my comment. You say you have a supply rail of +/- 15V. Let us look at the [DATASHEET](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm741.pdf) for the 741 Op-Amp:

[image]

You can see that the output will only get to a maximum of +/- 14V, which means your -13.04V that you measured is within its maximum output (depending on load).

Page 7 of the datasheet shows a diagram of the 741 internal schematic. As you can see, it is mainly resistors and transistors, these will have losses over them, which is why the op amp can never output all the way to its supply rail.

Comment: Ahhh~~~~ thank you !